# How can I format a fraction to look like a formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to make a table of common Z-transforms that I would like to have in a certain list. Most lists i find are not fully inclusive, or have things I don't really need. So I decided to make my own, and one thing I can't seem to find how to do is make 1/(1-az⁻¹) look like

[image: formatted picture]

Anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: In a spreadsheet? 1) That would have to be an image. 2) You'd probably need to download it from a LaTeX string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert > Image > By URL

```
http://quicklatex.com/cache3/fe/ql_541f902d54fc849265711ca166712dfe_l3.png
```

Generated from [QuickLatex](http://quicklatex.com/) with

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1-az^{-1}}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: perfect! Thats exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! If you need help with other formulas, you can learn LaTeX here https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/